# Get iteration row number from foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to pick out the row number that matches the user I am logged in as.

So I created a leaderboard for a school and each have a login (WordPress users), on their profile they are assigned to a school name by `$user_info->schoolname` and I am outputting a leaderboard of schools by points.

What I need to do it just output my schools position outside of the loop:

```
<?php 

$i= 1;

// get posts
$posts = get_posts(array(
  'post_type'     => 'schools',
  'posts_per_page'  => -1,
  'meta_key'      => 'signups',
  'orderby'     => 'meta_value_num',
  'order'       => 'DESC'
));

if( $posts ): ?>

  <table class="table">

  <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 

    setup_postdata( $post )

    ?>

    <tr>
      <th><?php echo $i++ ?></th>
      <td><?php the_title(); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo the_field('signups') . ' Signups'; ?></td>
    </tr>

  <?php endforeach; ?>

  </table>

  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi @Dan, can you clarify the question a bit? I'm not sure to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @damienc sure, so... I am outputting the leaderboard ok and it orders it by score which is what I want, but what I am trying to do is gather information from the leaderboard so for instance I want to be able to return the value back of the position the school is on the leader board. I have put in an iteration on the leader so I would like to somehow count which row the school is on by its name? So for instance output something like: Your 'Example School' is currently in position number#!

Comment: Ah I see. Do schools have their own identifier? Storing this to the database seems the easiest way of doing it, but if you can't change the db you could use an intermediary mapper that holds schools and their score, then display it to the user. The latter sounds hacky though.

Comment: @damienc Because its wordpress I am unable to really do anything with the Database, but im sure each school has an identifier, is there a way to like find the schools name and say its in position x? Or like count the rows?

Comment: You could write a custom function (a plugin) that does this kind of computation I think. I've left WP for quite a while, but that's what I'd have done a couple of years ago :-)

Comment: Is there not liker a real simple way to find which row the school is on by using the key you kindly offered me above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128046/discussion-between-dan-and-damienc).